# Cracking capture files moved from Kali [VM] to Mac issue

Tags: macos, aircrack-ng, kali-linux

I'm using Kali on VMware Fusion. I captured a WPA handshake on the VM and saved it as `test.cap`. I then sent it to my MAC for a higher keys per second using File Sharing on the MAC with SMB (Samba) ticked.

- Could anyone explain to me why aircrack on my MAC doesn't find the key but aircrack on Kali does?
- Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem to this question. I used KISMac to capture the handshakes instead of transfering the capture file from airodump-ng. I then used aircrack on the mac and used a custom wordlist (With the known password in it) which worked succesfully.